# Put two symbols in a legend at the same time

Tags: plotting, legending

If I have the following data:

```
lengthscale1SB = {{0, 3.8070469267093143`}, {0, 
    3.6334805550267246`}, {0, 3.5421004645025067`}, {0, 
    3.1777415559882036`}, {0, 3.5382988573632863`}, {0, 
    2.8210206229841543`}};
```

Which plotted like:

```
qDSClabel = {"1 K/min", "2 K/min", "5 K/min", "10 K/min", "20 K/min", 
   "30 K/min"};

ListPlot[List /@ lengthscale1SB, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> 16, 
 Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {"y", 
     Row[{"x", " (", " units)"}]}), ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Cyan, Gray}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Defer /@ qDSClabel, {0.1, 0.25}]]
```

gives:

[image]

**Questions**

How can I put two symbols in the legend? For example, right now it is "circle" 1 K/min, "circle" 2 K/min and so on. So, specifically, how can I put something like "cirle" "triangle" 1 K/min and so on?. Can this be done easily modifying slightly: `PlotLegends -> Placed[Defer /@ qDSClabel, {0.1, 0.25}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListPlot[List /@ lengthscale1SB, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> 16, 
 Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {"y", 
     Row[{"x", " (", " units)"}]}), ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Cyan, Gray}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[Automatic, Defer /@ qDSClabel, 
    LegendMarkers -> {Row[{"●", "▲"}, Spacer[2]], 12}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 20}, Spacings -> {.5, 0}], 
  {0.1, 0.25}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kglr. However, I am having a problem: when I use: `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[PointLegend[Automatic, Defer /@ qDSClabel, 
   LegendMarkers -> {Row[{Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12], 
       Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", 16]}, Spacer[2]], 12}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 20}, Spacings -> {.5, 0}], {0.12, 0.25}]` (I am using `Style` to increase size), the symbols get erase as they get bigger. How can I fix this?. In other words, I also want to be able to increase the size without erasing them

Comment: @John use a larger size, say `LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 20}`, to prevent clipping of markers.